# Odeint function from scipy.integrate gives wrong result

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, odeint, atan2

I use odeint function to solve a coupled differential equations system and plot one of the variables (theta_i) after the system is solved. My variable (theta_i) comes from the equation:

```
theta_i = np.arctan2(g1,g2)
```

where g1 ang g2 are variables calculated in the same function. The results have to be between -pi and pi and they are supposed to look like this (plot from matlab simulation):
[image]

However, when I try to plot theta_i after odeint has finished I get this(plot from my python code):

[image]

which is really weird. When I print the values of theta_i right after its calcumation (still inside the function) they look correct (between -0.2 and 0.5), so it has to be something with the result's storing and my implementation of odeint. All the other variables that come from the odeint solution are correct. I searched similar posts but nobody had the same problem with me. What might be the problem here? I am new to python and I use python 2.7.12. Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

added_mass_x = 0.03 # kg 
added_mass_y = 0.04 
mb = 0.3 # kg 
m1 = mb-added_mass_x 
m2 = mb-added_mass_y 
l1 = 0.07 # m 
l2 = 0.05 # m 
J = 0.00050797 # kgm^2 
Sa = 0.0110 # m^2 
Cd = 2.44 
Cl = 3.41 
Kd = 0.000655 # kgm^2 
r = 1000 # kg/m^3

c1 = 0.5*r*Sa*Cd 
c2 = 0.5*r*Sa*Cl 
c3 = 0.5*mb*(l1**2) 
c4 = Kd/J 
c5 = (1/(2*J))*(l1**2)*mb*l2 
c6 = (1/(3*J))*(l1**3)*mb

theta_0 = 10*(np.pi/180) # rad 
theta_A = 20*(np.pi/180) # rad 
f = 2 # Hz

t = np.linspace(0,100,8000) # s

def direct(u,t):
    vcx = u[0]
    vcy = u[1]
    wz = u[2]
    psi = u[3]
    x = u[4]
    y = u[5]
    vcx_i = u[6]
    vcy_i = u[7]
    psi_i = u[8]
    wz_i = u[9]
    theta_i = u[10]
    theta_deg_i = u[11]

    # Subsystem 1
    omega = 2*np.pi*f # rad/s
    theta = theta_0 + theta_A*np.sin(omega*t) # rad
    theta_deg = (theta*180)/np.pi # deg
    thetadotdot = -(omega**2)*theta_A*np.sin(omega*t) # rad/s^2

    # Subsystem 2
    vcxdot = (m2/m1)*vcy*wz-(c1/m1)*vcx*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))+(c2/m1)*vcy*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))*np.arctan2(vcy,vcx)-(c3/m1)*thetadotdot*np.sin(theta)
    vcydot = -(m1/m2)*vcx*wz-(c1/m2)*vcy*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))-(c2/m2)*vcx*np.sqrt((vcx**2)+(vcy**2))*np.arctan2(vcy,vcx)+(c3/m2)*thetadotdot*np.cos(theta)
    wzdot = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx*vcy-c4*wz*wz*np.sign(wz)-c5*thetadotdot*np.cos(theta)-c6*thetadotdot
    psidot = wz

    # Subsystem 3
    xdotdot = vcxdot*np.cos(psi)-vcx*np.sin(psi)*wz+vcydot*np.sin(psi)+vcy*np.cos(psi)*wz # m/s^2
    ydotdot = -vcxdot*np.sin(psi)-vcx*np.cos(psi)*wz+vcydot*np.cos(psi)-vcy*np.sin(psi)*wz # m/s^2
    xdot = vcx*np.cos(psi)+vcy*np.sin(psi) # m/s
    ydot = -vcx*np.sin(psi)+vcy*np.cos(psi) # m/s

    # Subsystem 4
    vcx_i = xdot*np.cos(psi_i)-ydot*np.sin(psi_i)
    vcy_i = ydot*np.cos(psi_i)+xdot*np.sin(psi_i)
    psidot_i = wz_i
    vcxdot_i = xdotdot*np.cos(psi_i)-xdot*np.sin(psi_i)*psidot_i-ydotdot*np.sin(psi_i)-ydot*np.cos(psi_i)*psidot_i
    vcydot_i = ydotdot*np.cos(psi_i)-ydot*np.sin(psi_i)*psidot_i+xdotdot*np.sin(psi_i)+xdot*np.cos(psi_i)*psidot_i

    g1 = -(m1/c3)*vcxdot_i+(m2/c3)*vcy_i*wz_i-(c1/c3)*vcx_i*np.sqrt((vcx_i**2)+(vcy_i**2))+(c2/c3)*vcy_i*np.sqrt((vcx_i**2)+(vcy_i**2))*np.arctan2(vcy_i,vcx_i)
    g2 = (m2/c3)*vcydot_i+(m1/c3)*vcx_i*wz_i+(c1/c3)*vcy_i*np.sqrt((vcx_i**2)+(vcy_i**2))+(c2/c3)*vcx_i*np.sqrt((vcx_i**2)+(vcy_i**2))*np.arctan2(vcy_i,vcx_i)

    A = 12*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+np.pi) # eksiswsi tail_frequency apo simulink
    if A>=0.1:
        wzdot_i = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx_i*vcy_i-c4*wz_i**2*np.sign(wz_i)-c5*g2-c6*np.sqrt((g1**2)+(g2**2))
    elif A<-0.1:
        wzdot_i = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx_i*vcy_i-c4*wz_i**2*np.sign(wz_i)-c5*g2+c6*np.sqrt((g1**2)+(g2**2))
    else:
        wzdot_i = ((m1-m2)/J)*vcx_i*vcy_i-c4*wz_i**2*np.sign(wz)-c5*g2


    if g2>0:
        theta_i = np.arctan2(g1,g2)
    elif g2<0 and g1>=0:
        theta_i = np.arctan2(g1,g2)-np.pi
    elif g2<0 and g1<0:
        theta_i = np.arctan2(g1,g2)+np.pi
    elif g2==0 and g1>0:
        theta_i = -np.pi/2
    elif g2==0 and g1<0:
        theta_i = np.pi/2
    elif g1==0 and g2==0:
        theta_i = 0
    theta_deg_i = (theta_i*180)/np.pi
    #print theta_deg_i


    return [vcxdot, vcydot, wzdot, psidot, xdot, ydot, vcxdot_i, vcydot_i, psidot_i, wzdot_i, theta_i, theta_deg_i]

# arxikes synthikes 
vcx_0 = 0.1257 
vcy_0 = 0 
wz_0 = 0 
psi_0 = 0 
x_0 = 0 
y_0 = 0 
vcx_i_0 = 0.1257 
vcy_i_0 = 0 
psi_i_0 = 0 
wz_i_0 = 0 
theta_i_0 = 0.1745 
theta_deg_i_0 = 9.866 
u0 = [vcx_0, vcy_0, wz_0, psi_0, x_0, y_0, vcx_i_0, vcy_i_0, psi_i_0, wz_i_0, theta_i_0, theta_deg_i_0]

u = odeint(direct, u0, t, tfirst=False)

vcx = u[:,0] 
vcy = u[:,1] 
wz = u[:,2] 
psi = u[:,3] 
x = u[:,4] 
y = u[:,5] 
vcx_i = u[:,6] 
vcy_i = u[:,7] 
psi_i = u[:,8] 
wz_i = u[:,9] 
theta_i = u[:,10] 
theta_deg_i = u[:,11] 
print theta_i

plt.figure(17) 
plt.plot(t,theta_i,'r-',linewidth=1,label='theta_i') 
plt.xlabel('t [s]') 
plt.title('theta_i [rad] (Main body CF)') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: `odeint` works generally nicely. The code is a bit long, so it is difficult for someone to look it and assess at simple view what it could be wrong, specially without knowing the system. I can recommend a couple of things: 1) use a more restricted time interval (e.g. `t = np.linspace(0,2,8000)` ) 2) Plot everything (i.e. use: "`for x in u.T: plt.plot(t,x); plt.show()`") And see if any variable looks strange

Comment: @Mstaino I have already plotted all the variables. The results look correct, except from theta_i. The only think I thing it might be the problem is that, in "return" the only variable which is not a differential equation is theta_i. I don't have a DE for that (i.e. theta_i_dot). Is this the problem ? for all the other variables in the system, I have their derivative in "return" and the state variable in "u"

Comment: Yes, it is probably the problem. Will post it as an answer so you can check the output and syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as you stated is that `theta_i` is not part of the gradient. When you formulate your `direct`, it should be of the form:

```
def direct(vector, t):
    return vector_dot
```

The quickest and dirtiest solution (without cleaning the code) is to use the function you already defined:

```
theta_i = [direct(u_i, t_i)[10] for t_i, u_i in zip(t, u)]
```

I used a a shorter interval: `t = np.linspace(0,10,8000)`. It yielded this:

[image]

**EDIT**: How to remove your theta from the integrator:

```
def direct(u, t):
    # your original function as it is

def direct2(u,t):
    return direct(u,t)[:9]

#now integrate the second function
u = odeint(direct2, u0, t)
```

Comment: I removed theta_i from the system (I only left the calculations of theta_i into the function). I placed:
    theta_i = [direct(u_i, t_i)[10] for t_i, u_i in zip(t, u)]
right after the 
   wz_i = u[:,9]
and I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't remove it. You should leave it as it is and ignore the integration results. In alternative build an integrating function that "throws away" the `theta_i` and `theta_i_deg` (see edit)

Comment: That worked pretty well! A you said it might be a "dirty" solution, but it works for me. I did the same with theta_deg_i and it is correct. Thank you @Mstaino! I was searching for days...